# OpenAFS install, packagemaker not found

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, openafs

I have tried to install openAFS directly from source code. This is for a MAC with OS Yosemite and I followed the instructions from an earlier question of mine:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959675/afs-and-yosemite-on-mac

However I can do everything until: sudo make packages, were I get the error:

packagemaker not found
make: *** [packages] Error 1

I looked into where this error occurs and it wants something in:

/Developer/usr/bin/packagemaker

Do I need another piece of software to finish this installation?

thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need PackageMaker installed. Note that this isn't technically required to build OpenAFS, but it is required to build the installer packages, which you probably want to do.

To install PackageMaker:

- Download "Auxiliary Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012" from somewhere in developer.apple.com. I think this is somewhere in [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).
- Copy PackageMaker.app into /Applications/Utilities
- Run:

```
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Utilities/PackageMaker.app/Contents/MacOS/PackageMaker /Developer/usr/bin/PackageMaker
```

Then you should be able to `make packages` in the OpenAFS source tree.

References:

- https://lists.openafs.org/pipermail/port-darwin/2013-November/001436.html
- https://lists.openafs.org/pipermail/port-darwin/2013-November/001444.html
- http://mid.gmane.org/CALCW7iK1jGarc+RNMu=3255FrOK3tk1aO75YWO0BCjPh6dggjA@mail.gmail.com
- http://mid.gmane.org/201311200208.rAK28uH8028025@hedwig.cmf.nrl.navy.mil